# C# client-Java Server data reading is slow?

Tags: java, c#, android

Yesterday I tried to create an Android app and a windows app.

**Android app** - Sends couple of **char[]** to the windows app using **WIFI**.

**Windows app** - C# server app, listens for clients data

However both programs works well, but the data reads from the server is kinda very slow.

I'm sending a data like this **00000000**. I have an gamepad connected to my phone via **otg**, and when I pressed **Button A** data becomes like this **10000000**. I even tried putting a **textview** in my android app, it works without any delay and when I press a button I can see the changed data set in my **textview**.

So I assumed the problem is between the server and the client. Is it impossible to solve this, as they are 2 different platforms? I have tried this kind of thing with **Xamarin**, it worked well. but I don't want to use **Xamarin** at this point for some specific reasons.

Let's say I press buttons A,B,C,D so the data is like this **11110000**, I clearly can see it in the android apps **TextView**, of course I will see this data in my server program, but only after a big delay, about 10-30 seconds.

My phone is Nexus 5. Is it a consequence of using 2 different platforms?

**Server Code:**

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartServer));
            thread.Start();
        }

        void StartServer()
        {
            Log("Running");
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
            server.Start();
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Log("Client connected");

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[8];
            NetworkStream inOpt = client.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                inOpt.Read(byteArray, 0, 8);
                Log(ASCIIEncoding.);
            }
        }

        void Log(string msg)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(Log), new object[] {msg});
                return;
            }
            logBox.Text = "";
            logBox.Text += msg + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

**Android Client Code:**

```
char[] keys = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList gameControllerDeviceIds = new ArrayList();
        int[] deviceIds = InputDevice.getDeviceIds();
        for (int deviceId : deviceIds) {
            InputDevice dev = InputDevice.getDevice(deviceId);

            int sources = dev.getSources();

            // Verify that the device has gamepad buttons, control sticks, or both.
            if (((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD)
                    || ((sources & InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK)
                    == InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK)) {
                // This device is a game controller. Store its device ID.
                if (!gameControllerDeviceIds.contains(deviceId)) {
                    gameControllerDeviceIds.add(deviceId);
                    Log.d("yolol", String.valueOf(deviceId));

                }
            }
        }

        //Log.d("yolol", InputDevice.getDevice(7).getName());
        new CheckUsageStartup().execute();
        Log.d("sss", Arrays.toString(keys));

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    byte[] toByteArray(String[] strong){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        for(int i = 0; i < strong.length; i++)
        {
            try{
                dos.writeUTF(strong[i]);
            }
            catch (IOException e){

            }
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    class CheckUsageStartup extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d(TAG + " PreExceute", "On pre Exceute......");

        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG + " DoINBackGround", "On doInBackground...");

            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.8", 8888);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");

                while(true){
                    writer.write(keys, 0, 8);
                    writer.flush();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                return "Instant";
            }
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... a) {
            Log.d(TAG + " onProgressUpdate", "You are in progress update ... " + a[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d(TAG + " onPostExecute", "" + result);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        int deviceId = event.getDeviceId();
        if (deviceId != -1) {
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_1:
                    keys[0] = '1';
                    Log.d("u", "po");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_2:
                    keys[1] = '1';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_3:
                    keys[2] = '1';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_4:
                    keys[3] = '1';
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                    keys[4] = '1';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                    keys[5] = '1';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                    keys[6] = '1';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                    keys[7] = '1';
                    break;
            }
            textView.setText(Arrays.toString(keys));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        int deviceId = event.getDeviceId();
        if (deviceId != -1) {
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_1:
                    keys[0] = '0';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_2:
                    keys[1] = '0';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_3:
                    keys[2] = '0';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_4:
                    keys[3] = '0';
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                    keys[4] = '0';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                    keys[5] = '0';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                    keys[6] = '0';
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                    keys[7] = '0';
                    break;
            }
            textView.setText(Arrays.toString(keys));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Here's the code. Please tell me possible solutions. Is it encoding do this much delay, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

This is code that was updating the textbox from earlier,

```
void Log(string msg)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(Log), new object[] {msg});
                return;
            }
            logBox.Text = "";
            logBox.Text += msg + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

I don't know what causes the problem, but after updating the textbox from the below code, it works well now.

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    logBox.Text = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, 8);
                });
```

It seems using the first method gives some unwanted delay.